# Sympy parse_expr, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'Symbol' and 'Symbol'

Tags: python, sympy

I'm quite new to this library.
Currently, I'm trying to parse a string `abc@mmw * 2 * 5` with the following code

```
parse_expr("abc@mmw * 2 * 5")
```

The result I epected to get is `10 * abc@mmw`, where `abc@mmw` is actually a function (name).
However, it seems that the parser treats @ as a Symbol.

The current workaround for this issue I came up with is replacing all @ with _ before parsing.
I am wondering is there any better way to deal with this kind of issue? Thanks!

Comment: `@` is a python operator, just like `+` and `*`

Comment: Detailed explanation about the `@` operator can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465

Comment: Better used slices.

Comment: Thanks all the comments and replies. I decided to stick with the workaround.